# jqGrid 3.5 - date is not being formatted at all

Tags: jquery, json, date, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid 3.5.2 and for the time being, I use the data from a local JSON object. After I read other answers about date formatting, I understood that the dates were not formatted properly in my JSON and I changed them all to ISO8601Long format. Now my dates look like this:

```
"2017-06-14T1:25:42.00"
```

The thing is, I attempt to format these dates and nothing happens. Here is my code snippet by which I try to format them:

```
sorttype: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'd/m/Y'}
```

I read that for data loaded locally, I need to use `sorttype` and not `formatter`, which I did. The strange thing is that if I console log the type of the value that I assume is date, it returns `string`, not `date` or `datetime`. So I assume there is a catch here.

Any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 0):

`formatoptions` will be used only if you would specify `formatter` option. You have to add `formatter: "date"` to solve your problem.

Comment: I tried to add back formatter: 'date' as well, but the date doesn't get formatted at all. Probably the fact that the date is passed in json as string might interfere with the formatting?

Comment: @IuliaMihet: Could you provide **the demo**, which reproduces the problem? You can get https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/zcx46o6x/ for example as basis and modify it so that one can see the problem, which you have.

Comment: @IuliaMihet: By the way, the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/zcx46o6x/1/ uses jqGrid 3.5.2 (instead of free jqGrid 4.14.1), it has the same `formatter: "date"` options and it has no problems too.

Comment: Here is a plunker with the exact config I use for jqGrid and as you can see, even if I promt jqGrid to sort "desc" by date, it's not doing it properly: https://plnkr.co/edit/nA7MosYyhTQQ36qpm7g6?p=info I am not sure if this is because I use such an old version and maybe the syntax changed in the meantime.